# Angularjs $resource get/post returning same result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm brand new to angular, so I'm probably doing things all wrong. My query is returning an array of objects like it should be. I then do a click event to test the post..it hits my web api just fine...but then it returns that same array from my get. I'm guessing this is cached? Why would my post show the results of my earlier get?

Edit - Sorry, I could have been more clear.  When I run my saveTest method, a post fires and my array saves, however the 'result' variable of that save..is the array from my original get.

```
app.directive('referenceSection', function () {
 return {
   restrict: 'E',
   templateUrl: '/app/loanapplication/views/reference-section.html',
   controller: function ($scope, referenceService) {
     $scope.json = angular.toJson($scope.referenceArray);
     $scope.referenceArray = [];

     referenceService.query().$promise.then(function (result) {
       $scope.referenceArray = result;
       }, function () {
       alert("fail");
     });

     $scope.saveTest = function () {
       referenceService.save(angular.toJson($scope.referenceArray)).$promise.then(function (result) {
       var x = result;
       }, function () {
       alert("save fail");
     });
   }
 }
 };
});
```

Service

```
app.factory('referenceService', function ($resource) {
 var requestUri = '/api/reference';
 return $resource(requestUri)
});
```

Web api

```
public class ReferenceController : BaseController
{

  public HttpResponseMessage Get()
  {
    List<WebReference> references = new List<WebReference>();

    WebReference reference = new WebReference();
    WebReference reference2 = new WebReference();

    reference.Name = "Andrew";
    reference.Relationship = "QuickSupport";
    reference.Id = 1;

    reference2.Name = "Josh";
    reference2.Relationship = "Hansen";
    reference2.Id = 2;

    references.Add(reference);
    references.Add(reference2);

    if (references == null) throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

    return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<WebReference>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, references);
  }

  public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]WebReference[] references)
  {
    try
    {
      var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
      return msg;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
    }
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
 referenceService.query().$promise.then(function (result) {
   $scope.referenceArray = result;
```

After this, you need to call `$scope.$apply()` to inform angular of your changes made to be bound. If I guessed your question correctly .

:-)

Answer (score 0):

From where you are reading response? From x that is not available outside then function or it is mistake to not attach it to `referenceArray`

```
referenceService.save(angular.toJson($scope.referenceArray)).$promise
.then(function (result) {
  var x = result;
}, function () {
  alert("save fail");
});
```

Comment: When I debug and break on "var x = result", the 'result' variable contains the array from the original get

Comment: What server returns, can you check what is in body in XHR response?